# Converting Dataset to IList

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using `SqlHelper` to execute the stored procedure in the DB.

In a namespace called constants i defined something like this

```
public class ShowInstitutes
{
   public string InstituteName { get; set; }
   public string InstituteCity { get; set; }
   public int InstituteId { get; set; }
}
```

In the DAL layer I am trying to execute stored proc and get results in `IList` format

```
public IList<ShowInstitutes> ShowInstitutes(int instituteId)
{
   return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dBConnection, "usp_SPName");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<>

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that. Try this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107220/convert-dataset-to-object-list

Answer (score 3):

```
public IList<ShowInstitutes> ShowInstitutes(int instituteId)
{
   var d = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dBConnection, "usp_SPName");

   var myData = d.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(data => new ShowInstitutes{
       InstituteName = data.Field<string>("InstituteName "),
       InstituteCity = data.Field<string >("InstituteCity "),
       InstituteId = data.Field<int>("InstituteId ")
   });
   var list = myData.ToList();
   return list;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , it was my mistake!

Answer (score 3):

You can converting your Dataset result to IList like this.

```
public IList<ShowInstitutes> ShowInstitutes(int instituteId)
{
    var dataTable = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dBConnection, "usp_SPName");
    var SourceLists = new List<ShowInstitutes>();
    for (var index = 0; index < dataTable.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        SourceLists.Add(new ShowInstitutes
        {
            InstituteName = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[index]["Columnname"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            InstituteCity = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[index]["Columnname"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            InstituteId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[index]["Columnname"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        });
    }
    return SourceLists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class info
{
    public string counter
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string marks
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<info> getdata()
    {
        string c = "Data Source=bla ;bla ;bla";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
        DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, CommandType.Text, "SELECT * from table1");

        var list = (ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(
            df =>
            new info
            {
                age = df[0].ToString(),
                counter = df[1].ToString(),
                id = df[3].ToString(),
                name = df[4].ToString(),
                marks = df[2].ToString()
            })).ToList();

        return list;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        info a =new info();
        List<info> list1= a.getdata();
        foreach (var info in list1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.name+" "+info.age+" "+info.marks);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't focus on variable name.Aim is to show conversion of data set into  list :)

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to how your code addresses the question. What is the problem with the OP's code, and how are you resolving it? Please add the explanation by editing the answer rather than responding in comments.