# Serializing objects into XML repository

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, crud

I like `XmlSerializer`, because of its fire-and-forget operation.  I can give `XmlSerializer` the object to serialize and the file to serialize to, and `XmlSerializer` will sort out the property names and values.

```cs
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(projectPath + "\\" + m_projectDescriptionFileName);  // create new project description file (XML)
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerContactInfoViewModel));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, contactInfo);
xmlWriter.Close();
```

I like LINQ to XML for its ability to navigate.  Here's an example of a method for editing an object that's stored in XML (adapted from [Greg's blog](http://www.gregjopa.com/2011/04/crud-operations-with-xml-data-in-asp-net-mvc-3/).  There are also snippets for Insert and Delete.)

```cs
public void EditBilling(Billing billing)
{
    XElement node = m_billingData.Root.Elements("item").Where(i => (int)i.Element("id") == billing.ID).FirstOrDefault();

    node.SetElementValue("customer", billing.Customer);
    node.SetElementValue("type", billing.Type);
    node.SetElementValue("date", billing.Date.ToShortDateString());
    node.SetElementValue("description", billing.Description);
    node.SetElementValue("hours", billing.Hours);

    m_billingData.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Billings.xml"));
}
```

As you can see, property names and values are written out in the code, unlike `XmlSerializer`.

I would like to be able able to store multiple objects of different types in the same XML file (adding them at different times, not all at once). I would like to be able to deserialize them one at a time. I would like to update them one at a time.

- Is there a way to combine the LINQ navigation with fire-and-forget convenience of `XmlSerializer` ?
- Is `XmlSerializer` a right kind of tool for this?
- Is there something better (short of setting up a proper database)?
- Am I looking for something that goes by a different name?

Any suggestion, insight or reference is really appreciated!

Comment: Am I missing something, or does ADO.NET fall short for you somewhere?

Comment: @WesleyLong  May be it is I that's missing something, and your comment addresses my last question "*looking for something that goes by a different name?*"  In the meantime, I'll go look up what ADO.NET can do to XML.

Comment: I just guessing here, but couldnt you create a baseObjectXmlElement which stores Xml as string/data and a typedescriptorstring? so you can store anything in the data seection and deserialize it using the typestring

Comment: @WesleyLong  Can ADO.NET infer the table and field structure of my data object?  For instance, `XmlSerializer` can infer.  If I add or remove fields from my data class, I want the serialization scheme to adapt (infer) without my intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Using XmlSerializer will not directly allow you to serialize multiple objects of different types into the same file. You need to tweak the reading of the xml file a bit before using XmlSerializer.

You have two options.

**Option #1:**

The first one being that you have a wrapper class as suggested in comments, which holds your objects. You can then use XmlSerializer to Serialize/Deserialize that specific type. You cannot directly pick a part of the xml and serialize that. This will allow you to directly serialize and deserialize the whole type/class.

Quick sample:

```cs
public class Container {
    public MyType My {get;set;}
    public OtherType Other {get;set;}
}

Container container = new Container();
...
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
serializer.Serialize(aWriter, container);

// deserialize

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("container.xml");
Container c = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Container;
```

**Option #2:**

You can read the xml file using `XmlReader`, and use [ReadToDecendant(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayf5ffy5(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the current xml representation of your object (let's call it `MyType`) and read that xml using [ReadSubTree()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx). Using the result from `ReadSubTree()` and push that to the `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` method.

A quick sample would be something like:

```cs
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("objects.xml");
if (reader.ReadToDecendant("MyType"))
{
    var myTypeXml = reader.ReadSubTree(); // read the whole subtree  (type)
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)); // define the type
    MyType obj = serializer.Deserialize(myTypeXml); // 
}
```

*Writing the object would be the oposite way, Serialize() the type into a (xml)string, and then replace the corresponding xml in the file.*

You would really be better off using a database as data store, rather than xml. I hope you have a good reason for using files rather than a database.

Option #2 would probably be the best fit and most flexible implementation since it does not rely on wrapper classes.