# How to convert a dataset to a list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to convert a dataset to a list, there's a lot of example with 
datatable but with dataset I have not found.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107220/convert-dataset-to-list
example: `var empList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Employee{Name = dataRow.Field<string>("Name")}).ToList();`

Comment: Maybe add some code to show what you've tried? My first guess would be to use a .ToList() method.

Comment: Well a `DataSet` contains `DataTable`s, so if you've seen how to do this with `DataTable`s, and if you know how to get the tables out of a `DataSet`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert DataSet to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107220/convert-dataset-to-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use

```
 List<string> list = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

A `Dataset` is a collection of `DataTables`. All you need to do is iterate through each table of the `DataSet`. This data will typically be different structures, though, so you would want a `List` for each table.

```
foreach (var dt in myDataSet.Tables)
{
  var list =  dt.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(dr=> new 
                  { 
                   Name = dr.Field<string>("Name"), 
                   Valuw = dr.Field<string>("Value")
                  }).ToList();

  // do something with your list
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot.